# How to properly override jest mocks defined in __mocks__ folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I have a mock function called `registerAccount` defined in a module `fetchStuff`. This function fetches data from an API. To test it, I have defined a mock in a `__mocks__/fetchStuff.ts` file. This works just fine, but sometimes, I want to override the default implementation of those mocks, but I cannot figure out how to do that. I tried to follow the [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions) for "Mocking Modules" with the following code:

```
import * as fetchStuff from './fetchStuff';

jest.mock('./fetchStuff')

test('Jest can override __mocks__', () => {
  fetchStuff.registerAccount.mockResolvedValue(5);
});
```

But, when I try to run this code, I get the following error:

```
fetchStuff.registerAccount.mockResolvedValue is not a function
TypeError: fetchStuff.registerAccount.mockResolvedValue is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jordan/Documents/axle-mono/frontend/src/components/account/test/LoginPage.test.tsx:24:51)
    at Promise.then.completed (/home/jordan/Documents/axle-mono/frontend/node_modules/jest-circus/build/utils.js:391:28)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at callAsyncCircusFn (/home/jordan/Documents/axle-mono/frontend/node_modules/jest-circus/build/utils.js:316:10)
    at _callCircusTest (/home/jordan/Documents/axle-mono/frontend/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:218:40)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at _runTest (/home/jordan/Documents/axle-mono/frontend/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:155:3)
    at _runTestsForDescribeBlock (/home/jordan/Documents/axle-mono/frontend/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:66:9)
    at _runTestsForDescribeBlock (/home/jordan/Documents/axle-mono/frontend/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:60:9)
    at run (/home/jordan/Documents/axle-mono/frontend/node_modules/jest-circus/build/run.js:25:3)
    at runAndTransformResultsToJestFormat (/home/jordan/Documents/axle-mono/frontend/node_modules/jest-circus/build/legacy-code-todo-rewrite/jestAdapterInit.js:170:21)
    at jestAdapter (/home/jordan/Documents/axle-mono/frontend/node_modules/jest-circus/build/legacy-code-todo-rewrite/jestAdapter.js:82:19)
    at runTestInternal (/home/jordan/Documents/axle-mono/frontend/node_modules/jest-runner/build/runTest.js:389:16)
    at runTest (/home/jordan/Documents/axle-mono/frontend/node_modules/jest-runner/build/runTest.js:475:34)
    at TestRunner.runTests (/home/jordan/Documents/axle-mono/frontend/node_modules/jest-runner/build/index.js:101:12)
    at TestScheduler.scheduleTests (/home/jordan/Documents/axle-mono/frontend/node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:333:13)
    at runJest (/home/jordan/Documents/axle-mono/frontend/node_modules/@jest/core/build/runJest.js:404:19)
    at _run10000 (/home/jordan/Documents/axle-mono/frontend/node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:320:7)
    at runCLI (/home/jordan/Documents/axle-mono/frontend/node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:173:3)
    at Object.run (/home/jordan/Documents/axle-mono/frontend/node_modules/jest-cli/build/cli/index.js:155:37)
```

However, this *same exact code* works perfectly well if I remove the `__mocks__` folder. Is there a way to override an implementation defined in `__mocks__`? Or will jest always try to use the implementation in `__mocks__` and cause errors if you try to mock the function any other way? Is there a way to disable jest from looking in the `__mocks__` folder temporarily?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this working (credit to [Asis Garcia](https://medium.com/trabe/mocking-different-values-for-the-same-module-using-jest-a7b8d358d78b)). The following code appears to override (or ignore) the manual mock specified in `__mocks__`:

```
import {registerAccount} from fetchStuff;

jest.mock('./fetchStuff', () => ({
    registerAccount: jest.fn(),
}))

test('Now it works', () => {
   registerAccount.mockResolvedValue(5);
});
```